# GHAssertEquals on an [NSArray count] verbosity

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, gh-unit

Can someone please tell me that this assert could be optimized?  Unit testing in iOS is driving me up the wall.  A simple assertion on the count of an NSArray should not be this verbose:

```
GHAssertEquals([[NSNumber numberWithInt:[caseArray count]] intValue], 
                             [[NSNumber numberWithInt:627] intValue], 
                                              @"array count equals");
```

**EDIT:** Suggested line below

```
GHAssertEquals([caseArray count], 627, @"array count equals");
```

produces this output:

```
Reason: Type mismatch -- array count equals

0   CoreFoundation                      0x01cfd02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0113ae7e objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01d85fb1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Tests                               0x00027711 -[GHTestCase failWithException:] + 33
4   Tests                               0x0001a0ed -[CaseTest testGetCaseArrayFromJSONArray] + 3293
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0114e663 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
6   Tests                               0x00022e19 +[GHTesting runTestWithTarget:selector:exception:interval:reraiseExceptions:] + 450
7   Tests                               0x0001ea90 -[GHTest run:] + 275
8   Tests                               0x000211ea -[GHTestGroup _run:] + 696
9   Tests                               0x00021513 -[GHTestGroup run:] + 130
10  Tests                               0x000211ea -[GHTestGroup _run:] + 696
11  Tests                               0x00021513 -[GHTestGroup run:] + 130
12  Tests                               0x000239a2 -[GHTestRunner runTests] + 257
13  Tests                               0x00023b12 -[GHTestRunner _runInBackground] + 79
14  Foundation                          0x00b85805 -[NSThread main] + 76
15  Foundation                          0x00b85764 __NSThread__main__ + 1304
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x983c7557 _pthread_start + 344
17  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x983b1cee thread_start + 34

FAIL (0.033s)
```

Comment: For one, you could just use caseArray.count instead of literally wrapping, then unwrapping the value in an NSNumber.

Comment: This does save me 1 x space and 2 x braces [] :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Type mismatch" is because GHAssertEquals requires that both arguments be the same type. `[caseArray count]` returns an unsigned integer. This doesn't match 627 which is a signed integer. So instead, compare against an unsigned 627, namely `627U`:

```
GHAssertEquals([caseArray count], 627U, @"array count equals");
```

Alternatively, you could use OCHamcrest to say

```
assertThat(caseArray, hasCountOf(627));
```

(OCHamcrest is compatible with GHUnit.)

Comment: Using the 627U worked :) thanks - going to checkout OCHamcrest next.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know GHAsserEquals, but your expression is equivalent to:

```
GHAssertEquals([caseArray count], 627, @"array count equals");
```

Comment: One would think that your answer would be sufficient, but generates output like so:  Reason: Type mismatch -- array count equals
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x01cfc02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01139e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x01d84fb1 -[NSException raise] + 17
 3   Tests                               0x00026bc1 -[GHTestCase failWithException:] + 33
 4   Tests                               0x0001a34f -[CaseTest testGetCaseArrayFromJSONArray] + 2831

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I'm confident that no matter what GHAssertEquals does, your code and my code are passing _exactly_ the same thing to it.  Maybe it requires objects?  You could try leaving off the intValue calls in your code.

Comment: @mccrackend, You should post that in question. What your code does and the code above are the same.

Comment: When I tried this suggestion, GHUnit fails with this Reason: Type mismatch -- array count equals.  I also agree that your code should be the exact same - I'm getting a bit frustrated using GHUnit and was hoping I was just way off here in how I'm using it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies - I tried removing the intValue calls and got a failure Reason: '<101b0308>' should be equal to '<20c30308>'. array count equals.

Comment: @mccrackend, I think Jon Reid has already given a perfect answer. Check it.